# Create a Sectioned UITableView using NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionaries` that I am trying to format for use with a `UITableView` that has sections based on one of the `NSDictionary keys`.

My `NSDicitonary` has two values

```
Name
Key
```

Key is a `NSString` of Numbers 1 - N

I have managed to create an `NSArray` of unique values I am using to populate the headers of each section, however I don't know how to split this `NSMutableArray` of NSDictionaries`into an`NSMutableArray of NSArrays of NSDictionaries`.. if that makes sense.

**UPDATE:**
to add more detail to my question, I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries.

```
{
 Name: Jack
 Key: 1
}
{
 Name: John
 Key: 1
}
{
 Name: Jack
 Key: 1
}
{
 Name: Jack
 Key: 2
}
{
 Name: Jack
 Key: 3
}
{
 Name: Sean
 Key: 3
}
{
 Name: Sally
 Key: 3
}
```

and I would like to display it in a UITableView like this

```
Section 1
- Jack
- John
- Jack
Section 2
- Jack
Section 3
- Jack
- Sean
- Sally
```

The areas I have identified that I need to do things in are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have managed to created a uniqueArray for sections

```
uniqueKeys = [xmlMutableArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Key"];
    uniqueKeys = [uniqueKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
    }];
```

Now I am left in the situation on how to find the number of rows in each section then pass the NSDictionary to an object in cellforrow to display the correct values into the cell?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
// testing
NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *testSample = @[@{@"1": @"hello1",@"2":@"world1",@"3":@"!1"},
                          @{@"1": @"hello2",@"2":@"world2",@"3":@"!2"},
                          @{@"1": @"hello3",@"2":@"world3",@"3":@"!3"}];
[test addObjectsFromArray:testSample];
NSMutableArray *sortedTestArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",test);

//get the max length of the nsdictionary
NSDictionary *item0 = [test objectAtIndex:0];
NSInteger maxLength = [[item0.allKeys lastObject] integerValue];
//key start from @"1"
for (int a = 1; a <= maxLength; a++) {
NSString *keyNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", a];
NSArray *sortedItem = [test valueForKey:keyNumber];
//the index starts from 0
[sortedTestArray insertObject:sortedItem atIndex:a-1];
}
//now the array will be like this,so the item in index 0 will be the key @"1"'s items. index 1 will be the key @"2"'s items...
NSLog(@"%@",sortedTestArray);
```

its original data:

```
(
        {
        1 = hello1;
        2 = world1;
        3 = "!1";
    },
        {
        1 = hello2;
        2 = world2;
        3 = "!2";
    },
        {
        1 = hello3;
        2 = world3;
        3 = "!3";
    }
)
```

output after sorted:

```
(
        (
        hello1,
        hello2,
        hello3
    ),
        (
        world1,
        world2,
        world3
    ),
        (
        "!1",
        "!2",
        "!3"
    )
)
```